# Call a Servelt (FIlter) using a form with an ajax request (must use authorization headers)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, header

I don't understand why it doesen't work. maybe the problem is in the url pattern? or i don't understand the flow of data? Note than only login.jsp can be modify. Response look link authorization header is not setted. I try all stuff find online but it doesen't work. Maybe you can prompt me a tutorial to do this. Thanks in advace for your time.

login.jsp

```
<html>
  <head>
<title>Login</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lsubmit").click(function(){
            var username = $("#lmail").val();
            var password = $("#lpsw").val();

            $.ajax({
                url : '/seller/*',
                method : 'POST',
                data: '{"username": "' + username + '", "password" : "' + 
                password + '"}',
                beforeSend : function(req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "inserirebase48");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script> </head>
<body>
 <form>
Email: <input type="text" id="lmail"><br>
Password: <input type="password" id="lpsw"><br>
<input type="button" id="lsubmit" value="Login">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

portion of web.xml

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>filterAuthenticationSeller</filter-name>
    <filter-class>servlets.FilterAuthenticationSeller</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterAuthenticationSeller</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/seller/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

FilterAutheniticationSeller.java

```
package servlets;

 import utils.authenticationManager.AuthenticationService;

 import javax.servlet.*;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import java.io.IOException;

import static utils.Utils.createResponse_UNAUTHORIZED;
@WebFilter(filterName = "FilterAuthenticationSeller")

public class FilterAuthenticationSeller implements Filter {

    AuthenticationService authenticationService = new 
       AuthenticationService();


      public void init(FilterConfig config) { }


       public void destroy() { }


public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        // if registration :  POST (path: '/users' + body) go on the next servlet
        // if login : POST (path: '/users/0' + body ) go on the next servlet
        if(httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals("POST")
                && httpServletRequest.getServletPath().contains("users")
                && (httpServletRequest.getPathInfo() == null || httpServletRequest.getPathInfo().equals("/0"))) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }

        // else, check user and go on OR unauthorized
        String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        boolean authenticated = authenticationService.authenticateSeller(authorization);
        if(authenticated)
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        else

            createResponse_UNAUTHORIZED((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove seller/* from the ajax post and specify proper Target url

Comment: what do you mean with Target url in this case?

Comment: From ajax post specify the servlet also which will handle the request

Comment: You specified seller/*

Answer (score 0):

Ok the url is correct but now the problem is with the ajax response, i add

```
                 .............
                success: function(){
                    alert('success!');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.status);
                }
                 ...........
```

status is 404, why?
I doesen't understand the last but two code line in FilterAutheniticationSeller.java, is it call itself with "doFilter"? 
i tested and authenticated with my param it's true

Comment: What is your context root place that first and then the seller/*